# Finding files not ending with specific extensions

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep

I'm making a bash script; how do I find files not ending with specific extensions?

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -type f -print | grep "\.\(?!psd\|xcf\).+$"
```

Thank you.

Comment: What about using -not parameter of find?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -type f ! -regex '.*\.(psd|xcf)$'
```

Or without regex:

```
find . -type f -not \( -name '*.psd' -o -name '*.xcf' \)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-v` grep param like this:

```
find . -type f -print | grep -v "${NOT_PATTERN}"
```

So, in your case you can use:

```
find . -type f -print | grep -v "\.\(psd|xcf\)$"
```

Documentation

> -v, --invert-match
>                 Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.

Comment: Really should have an anchor at the end like `"\.\(psd|xcf\)$"`

Comment: @dawg Thanks a lot for the comment, fixed now.