# unix find regex with patterns and not ending with another pattern

Tags: regex, unix, find

I search SO for something that might give me this simple answer and it seems to be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32192123/finding-files-not-ending-with-specific-extensions) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398471/regex-for-string-not-ending-with-given-suffix) (among many) but I simply can not get it to work.

I have files like

```
12_pattern1.yyy_zzz #find
13_pattern1.xxx.pattern2_xx 
12_yy_pattern1:xxx
14_pattern1.xxx_pattern2.xxx #find
12_xxx_zzz.yyy.xxx
14_pattern1.xxx.yyy #find
```

I need to find and remove files that start with `12` or `14`, have `_pattern1` immediately hereafter and do NOT end with `pattern2`.

I tried something along `find . -regex ".*/\(12_\|14_\)pattern1.*[^pattern2$]" -exec rm -f {} \;`

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
find . -regex "^\(12_\|14_\)pattern1.*" -not -regex "*.pattern2$"
```

Comment: Ah yes! This is perfect - I was trying to get it into the the one regex (just to be annoying: can you put the -not into the first regex as I tried?)

Comment: You can have a negated character class, but you can't simply negate a pattern in a regular expression. As far as i'm aware this is the only reasonable way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

`find` command supports `posix-*` flavors for Regular Expressions. It means you can't do it simply with `find`. However, if you could use `grep` then you could do it easily (but with help of two tools):

```
find . | grep -P '(14|12)_pattern1[^/]*$(?<!pattern2)'
```

Comment: Then to remove the found files could this be possible as in -exec rm {} \; with find

Comment: Aaw I didn't look at following options carefully. No it's not possible this way.